# Installation asks me to select "network" but displays network interface cards

Tags: wireless, system-installation

During Ubuntu installation (13.04 I believe):

[image]

The text says:

```
Connecting this computer to a wi-fi network allows you to install
third-party software, download updates, automatically detect your 
timezone, and install full support for your language.
```

Does this make any sense? Was it supposed to show available networks, but somehow shows smth different?

If not, what is going on then, and what is the password for my wireless network interface card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes sense since, before connecting to the network, it's asking  you what interface  do you want to use.  In your case, you only have one, but you could for example have two wireless cards, or a wireless and an Ethernet cable.
Anyway, if you're not sure, you can skip this step (not connect to the network). In fact, I always do that to skip the updating step during the installation. Once the system is installed, you can launch the regular update. The  result is the same but at least you can be using the system while updating instead of being staring at the install screen.

Comment: What you say makes sense, ie being asked to select an NIC. But that definitely does not match the text they put in the GUI. And how does it explain that they ask for a password? Furthermore, I did try and choose the NIC and clicking Next, but at least the next step was not about selecting WiFi, though it might have asked for that much later in the installation.

Comment: I see your point, maybe it's just a bug in the installer, and you could file a report for it :)